# Can a native ipad app written in HTML5+Javascript+CSS accomplish the same things as one written in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, html

I would like to build an iphone/ipad app that has social networking capabilities and the ability to sell magazines and specific articles. I would also like this app to be able to be as flexible as possible for future features.

Should I insist the developer use objective C or could he accomplish the same thing with HTML5 etc..

Comment: You mention a "native ipad app written in HTML5+JavaScript+CSS". This is misleading; a native app is written in Objective-C. There are frameworks to generate a native app from HTML5, but none that I can recommend.

Comment: Thats what I thought until i read about how apps written in HTML5 and converted via phonegap or titanium referred to as native apps. The question is if native native apps are distinguishable from native apps :p

Comment: @picciano that's also a bit misleading too. Phonegap absolutely makes a native app. It's just not written in Objective-C initially. There are reasons to go the Objective-C route and reasons to go the PhoneGap route, but both end up producing native iOS apps.

Comment: @chris...from an end-user POV, few if any folks would be able to distinguish a difference. In terms of functionality, there's way to distinguish the two and in terms of code details and what's under the hood, developers can certainly distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're the client, and have specific technical requirements, you should document them from a technical POV. If not, well that's why you're hiring a developer--for their expertise.

There's pros and cons to each and we'd need to have a lot more project details to be of any specific help for you.

Do note that selling items via an app has its own set of red tape political issues with Apple. You may want to tackle that aspect of the project first. If you don't want to route any payments through Apple so they can take their cut, then you might want to rethink the app model and consider a mobile web site avenue instead.

UPDATE:

In general, here's some high-level comparisons:

Native Apps:

Pros

- can access native device functionality directly
- can leverage the native UI more directly
- can be much more performant in situations like heavy game animation, 3-d, image/video editing, ec.
- may be smaller file sizes

Cons

- have to be written per-device
- different devices use different native IDEs and Languages

HTML5/Phonegap apps

- can be written with cross-platform Web standards
- can still leverage native device features to an extent
- are easier to port from device to device (though still takes effort)

Cons

- you won't be creating graphic-heavy game-type apps with it now
- may be a bit slower than a native app

Pure HTML5 local web app

This is different than something like a phonegap solution. PhoneGap takes HTML5 and compiles it into native code. That means you can send it through the app store. There's another option, however, where you put the HTML5 app on your web server, and then a user requests to keep it locally on their device. The advantage is that this allows you to bypass the app store completely (though in most situations, people prefer to go through the app store)

Comment: You bring up good points. The reason I ask is because I would like to inform myself before going into a meeting. If the developer is more familiar with the HTML5 root im sure he will pitch me that route. I want whats best for my app vs the developers time and expertise.

Comment: @chris: that's good. I added a few more bits of info to my answer in hopes that it'd help.

Comment: @chris: There are tons of use-cases where a web-app makes much more sense. Although a lot of clients just insist on a "native" app because they want it to be available in the app-store. This goes as far as an app that simply opens a webpage.. which is kinda sad :)

Comment: I definitely want the app to available via itunes. Apple is the target - not really interested in the android. The question is if something like phone gap or titanium will be able to create an interactive style magazine and social networking infrastructure that can be reliable and easy to grow with. Do you guys know of any well know complex apps that were built with HTML5 and converted via phonegap or titanium?

Comment: 'interactive magazine and social aspects' is something that likely could be built either natively or via HTML5+PhoneGap. It's going to come down to the specifics. But at this point, I'd say both are valid options.

Comment: looking through PhoneGap's portfolio of apps isn't very impressive.

Comment: would this be a testament to HTML5 conversion or unskilled developers?

Comment: The quality of an app has more to do with the quality of the design/development than it does the particular IDE that was used to build it.

Comment: Thanks DA youve been very helpful. Last thing I swear. Do you know if serving magazines via Adobes digital publishing can be done through HTML5+PhoneGap?

Comment: In otherwords, for every great Objecive-C app, there's a great PhoneGap app and for every crappy Objecive-C app, there's a crappy PhoneGap app. ;)

Comment: ah...Adobe adds a whole entirely different twist on things. Adobe and Apple aren't exactly bedfellows and have a rocky history. Adobe really wanted Flash to be an iOS IDE. And it was. Then it wasn't. But now I think it's back. I think you might need to post a new question that is more about the publishing format. Perhaps: ePub vs. Adobe Publishing vs. HTML5 vs. PDF vs. other? type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "no", you shouldn't insist the developer use Objective-C. At least not unless other requirements not mentioned dictate the need for a native app. As DA mentioned, there are App Store policies that would need to be complied with for native apps that can be avoided by creating a web app. Also, if you choose, it would be easier to produce a web app that could be used across other platforms rather than being restricted to the iPad.